# Collecting data from People Picker

Tags: sharepoint

I want to Collect the usernames added in the PeoplePicker and display them in the textbox on the click of "Add" button for a custom aspx page.

I tried many codes but its not working.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnpicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 for (int i = 0; i < userPicker.ResolvedEntities.Count; i++)
            {
                PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)userPicker.ResolvedEntities[i];
                Hashtable hstEntityData = picker.EntityData;
                string accountName = Convert.ToString(hstEntityData["AccountName"]);
                txtPicker.Text = "Count" + hstEntityData.Count.ToString();
                txtPicker.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            }
  }
```

Help Highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
protected void btnpicker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < userPicker.ResolvedEntities.Count; i++)
        {
            PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)userPicker.ResolvedEntities[i];
            yourTextBox.Text = "Count: " + new SPFieldUserValue(yourSPWebObject, Convert.ToInt32(picker.EntityData["SPUserID"]), picker.Key).User.Name;
        }
    }
```

This code will give all name of the users in your textbox.